# How to change the keyboard shortcut of Shake/Shake Gesture?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I updated Xcode to 9.0 and now <kbd>⌘R</kbd> no longer works in the iOS simulator to reload the application, and <kbd>⌘D</kbd> no longer opens the Developer Menu.

The new shortcut for the Developer Menu is <kbd>^⌘Z</kbd>, and there is no shortcut to reload the application anymore.

Is there any way that I can change the shortcut of the Shake Gesture from <kbd>^⌘Z</kbd> and get it back to <kbd>⌘D</kbd>?

[image: Hardware Settings for iOS Simulator - changed shortcuts]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Navigate to **System Preferences.app/Keyboard/Shortcuts**.

[image: Shortcuts settings]

2. Select **App Shortcuts** from the menu on the right and click on the **plus sign** (**+**).

[image: App Shortcuts option]

3. Select **Simulator** as the application from the drop-down list.
4. Enter **Shake** (Xcode 11 and above) or **Shake Gesture** (Xcode 10 and earlier) for the menu title and press <kbd>⌘D</kbd> while the Keyboard Shortcut menu is in focus.
5. Click on **Add** to save changes.

[image: Shake Gesture as custom shortcut]

Comment: How did you get to System Preferences on version 11.0? I remember it was under Simulator, but not anymore

Comment: This is System Preferences.app, located inside Applications.

Comment: For some reason I don't have **Simulator** under App Shortcuts: https://ibb.co/mRpk3k

Comment: You should select it from the drop-down list.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Any possible way to get `Command+R` back to Reload the application?

Comment: It's the same method, just with a different menu item.

Comment: As of today, the name of the menu is "Shake" and not "Shake Gesture" anymore

Comment: @suprandr Thanks for the notice, I'll edit my answer!